Display live data from an external source in Google Earth Engine
I am collecting data from a raspberry pi. I want to show the data in real time on a map in Google Earth Engine. I have seen at Access external API from Google Earth Engine that there is no way to use an external API to gather data.
Is there any other way to import the live data to GEE or do you know of any other mapping services that would allow live data to be imported through an API?
